# How can I create a method to get a string of an element and assert its changes

Tags: c#, selenium, methods

I'm quite new to unit testing and c#.

I have an area on a page with a url: https://www.testurl.com (example)

I have a couple of tick boxes that can change the displayed url on the page.

Example of tick boxes: Http, .net, testurl2

There boxes will change the value of the url and i need to check if the url does change when those boxes are ticked.

How can i create a method for the url so i can call it every  time a box is ticked and use an assert for the expected value?

I have created a Method for the test url as follows:

```
void TestUrl()
            {
                string url = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='ui action input'] input[type='text']")).Text;
                
            }
```

And i tried to assert it this way (lets say, after clicking the http:// tick box, changing https:// to http://):

```
string httpUrl = "http://testurl.com";
Assert.AreEqual(httpUrl, TestUrl());
```

I get the following issue: Argument 2> cannot convert from void to object.

I understand the issue, but i cannot think on a way to get to use the method `TestUrl()` as i want to.

Hopefully the question is clear, Using examples as i cannot use the urls i am working on as they are confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change

```
void TestUrl()
            {
                string url = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='ui action input'] input[type='text']")).Text;
                
            }
```

to be

```
string TestUrl()
            {
                return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='ui action input'] input[type='text']")).Text;
                
            }
```

Now your method will return `string` so you can compare it

Comment: And every time i call TestUrl() it will be taking the updated value correct?

Comment: Yes, sure. Since you are each time finding the element again according to its locator.

Comment: You are an absolute legend an i have no words to thank you! Just tested and it worked :)

Comment: I'm happy :) If so please accept my answer. You are welcome to ask any more question :)

Comment: I accepted the answer but i need 15 rep to upvote. Thank you once again. If i can confirm with you, all methods in C# need a "return" correct?

Comment: No, only in case you want to use something that this method can return. Otherwise it can stay void.